# How to connect sipml5 client to Officesip server

Tags: svn, websocket, sip

I've installed **Officesip** and created two user accounts (Alice and Bob) in the default domain (`officesip.local`) I want to connect two instances of sipml5 client to it and make a call between them, but I can't even login to sipml5 live demo.

What should I enter into the following fields:

- Public Identity
- Realm

I've tried the following:

1) Added port forwarding between the   tags:

```js
<portForwardings>
    <clear />
    <add protocol="Tcp" localEndpoint="192.168.1.5:5060" externalEndpoint="195.20.232.5:5060" />
    <add protocol="Udp" localEndpoint="192.168.1.5:5060" externalEndpoint="195.20.232.5:5060" />
</portForwardings>
```

2) I tried these inputs for public identity and realm
`sip:alice@officesip.local` and `officesip.local`, also 
`sip:alice@192.168.1.5:5060` and `192.168.1.5:5060.`

[Here](https://www.doubango.org/sipml5/call.htm?svn=250#) is the link to sipml5 live demo.

Comment: Go to the Expert mode and that is where you will configure your WebSocket Server URL, in your extract I only see TCP and UDP remember that SipML5 works with WS and WSS as transport, does OfficeSIP supports it?

Comment: Have you looked into this video: http://jssip.net/documentation/misc/interoperability/officesip/ this may help is jssip but simiar logic